# Why might HR ask what my favorite color is?

Tags: human-resources

Why might HR ask what my favorite color is? I was asked what my favorite color is even though I've been working for the company for 6 months already and got a decent performance review. I am wondering why they may ask such a question. Should I be worried in anyway? Are they trying to find an excuse to fire me, or am I too paranoid? What should I do to follow up on this? Because it seems really weird. I know this question is asked during interviews to gauge personality, but I am wondering how they can ask a question like that.

Comment: What was the occasion? Was it the only question asked? Please give us an idea about the context.

Comment: And were other people asked the same question or only you?

Comment: "What is your favorite color?" Isn't a typical business or HR question so this isn't something we can help you with. But I can't imagine a scenario in which a reasonable company or reasonable HR would use your favorite color as an excuse to fire you or where your answer could hurt you.

Comment: Sounds like someone has an {item} colored {favorite_color} coming his way!

Comment: The real question here is what *IS* your favourite color? Don't leave us hanging!

Comment: Blue, no Aaaahhhhhh!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess but maybe you're going to get a gift for passing probation where there are a choice of colours?

You're overthinking it - Don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be worried in anyway?

I don't see a reason why you should be worried.

> Are they trying to find an excuse to fire me, or am I too paranoid?

Perhaps you are being too paranoid, yes. Such question could have several goals, including, perhaps, knowing what color would your surprise gift would be (or similar, as mentioned in comments).

> What should I do to follow up on this?

No need to follow up. You answer the question and move on. You could politely ask why they want such information after answering, so you clear your doubts about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You've seen Monty Python and the Holy Grail too many times. You are being paranoid.

And if you don't mind me saying so, it sounds like you are terrified of HR and people in positions of authority. Relax. If it were truly some kind of mind game that comes back to haunt you, you should thank them for exposing that this is how they operate as you look for another employer.

People in these kinds of roles have all sorts of silly reasons for asking this question. It might be to give your name a special color on a spreadsheet. It is a little weird to not tell you why, but as others have pointed out, it's 99.9999999% more likely to be some kind of gift that shows up on your doorstep in a couple weeks (not a letterbomb).